# PHP: Telephone number parsing

Tags: php, validation, parsing

I'm looking for some way to validate telephone numbers in PHP, which may be entered in any of the various formats that exist.  If it helps, I'm able to restrict the problem's domain to just U.S. phone numbers (or international numbers - one or the other, but not both).

I've tried looking for custom filters for `filter_var()`, an equivalent to `strtotime()` for phone numbers, or just plain vanilla parsing libraries, but haven't had much luck.

If needed, I can design a custom solution, but I prefer not to if one already exists, because A) mine will surely not be as robust, and B) I don't like reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex, the following will Match things like 3334445555, 333.444.5555, 333-444-5555, 333 444 5555, (333) 444 5555 and all combinations thereof.
and then replaces all those with (333) 444-5555

```
preg_replace('\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})', '(\1) \2-\3', $text);
```

Comment: I should also point out you can put the above in an if statement if you're not sure if the number is valid or not and want to return an error if the above returns false.

Answer (score 0):

'Parsing' phone numbers is not a native PHP thing to do.

You need to specify yourself what 'valid' phonenumbers are - this should be done by validating the input up against a specified format or perhaps a regular expression.

There is no way PHP can know what 'a valid phonenumber' is.

Comment: The same could be said about date/times, but yet `strtotime()` and equivalents exist natively, despite the ridiculous number of different possible formats, both nationally and internationally.  It uses a "best guess" parsing algorithm, and that's all I'm looking for really.

Comment: @drrcknlsn I don't agree; [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) clearly states what `strtotime()` consider valid and parsible inputs.

Comment: If PHP can know what a valid date/time is based on a set of clearly defined rules, then there's absolutely no reason it can't know what a valid phone number is.  The fact that it doesn't natively is likely just because nobody's taken the time to implement it.  Not because it can't be done.  That's all I was saying.

Comment: @drrcknlsn No, that's not what you were saying - you were saying that you can put almost any input into `strtotime()` and parsing is based on 'buest guess' - but that's not true alas the documentation. Nobody has developed an extension to 'parse a phonenumber' which is why it's not a native PHP thing to do - but parsing time strings is. Nobody is stopping you - or anyone else - to create such an extension; but none has done so - which again puts you the in the same spot; parsing phone numbers is not a native PHP thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of all US phone number formats, but i'm guessing this is a general idea that you can extend:

```
function validate_phone($phone) {
  // replace everything except numbers
  $phone = preg_replace('~[^\dx]~', '', $phone);

  return preg_match('~^\d{11}(x\d{4})?$~', $phone);
}


// $phone = 12345678901;
$phone = '1-234-567-8901x1234';
$valid = filter_var($phone, FILTER_CALLBACK, array(
  'options' => 'validate_phone'
));

if ($valid) {
  echo "It's valid!";
};
```

This code supports or eleven digit numbers(with dashes, spaces, dots inside) and extended format with x2134 suffix.